# How to remove if the json data is equals to nil?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsjsonserialization

```
category =     (
                {
            "category_id" = 18;
            column = 1;
            description = "Electrician Works";
            image = "images/Electrician.jpg";
            "meta_description" = "Electrician Works";
            "meta_keyword" = "Electrician Works";
            name = Electrician;
            "parent_id" = "";
            "sort_order" = 3;
            status = enable;
            subcategory =             (
            );
            top = "";
        },
                {
            "category_id" = 19;
            column = 1;
            description = "Plumbing Works";
            image = "images/Plumber.png";
            "meta_description" = "Plumbing Works";
            "meta_keyword" = "Plumbing Works";
            name = Plumber;
            "parent_id" = "";
            "sort_order" = 1;
            status = disable;
            subcategory =             (
            );
            top = "";
        },
{
            "category_id" = 37;
            column = 0;
            description = "";
            image = "images/SUV.jpg";
            "meta_description" = "";
            "meta_keyword" = "";
            name = SUV;
            "parent_id" = 20;
            "sort_order" = 3;
            status = enable;
            subcategory =             (
            );
            top = "";
        }
```

if parent_id ="" then the others values have to remove.

i am stored the values name & parent_id here

```
 {
    name = Microwave;
    parent = "";
},
    {
    name = Hatchback;
    parent = 20;
},
    {
    name = Sedan;
    parent = 20;
},
    {
    name = SUV;
    parent = 20;
}
```

if parent id is not there then i have to remove from array ,friends any body help me to find out this problem.

```
-(void)responseFunction:(NSMutableDictionary*)response
{
    BOOL sucess;
    sucess =[response objectForKey:@"sucess"];
    if(!sucess)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",response);
        arrDicCategory=[response objectForKey:@"category"];
        for(NSDictionary *dicAllCategory in arrDicCategory)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *dicStorage=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            [dicStorage setObject:[[dicAllCategory objectForKey:@"name"] length] !=0?[dicAllCategory objectForKey:@"name"]:@"" forKey:@"name"];
//            [dicStorage setObject:[dicAllCategory objectForKey:@"parent_id"]!=Nil?[dicAllCategory objectForKey:@"parent"]:@"" forKey:@"parentid"];
            [dicStorage setObject:[dicAllCategory objectForKey:@"parent_id"] forKey:@"parent"];
            [arrDicName addObject:dicStorage];
            NSLog(@"%@",arrDicName);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my code ...

```
I NEED OUTPUT LIKE THIS

    name = Hatchback;
    parent = 20;


    name = Sedan;
    parent = 20;


    name = SUV;
    parent = 20;
```

I am trying to remove the values by using this code:

```
for(int i=0; i<arrDicName.count ; i++)
        {
          if([[arrDicName objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"parent"]==Nil)
            {
                [arrDicName removeObject:[[arrDicName objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"parent"]];
                NSLog(@"AfterRemovingFromThearray%@",arrDicName);
            }
        }
```

Some thing wrong in my code i understood but i can't find it so finally i came here help me friends.

Comment: Why an array of dictionaries, when a single dictionary will do (quicker look-up)?

Comment: inside for loop i am storing the values .....

Comment: Is there some reason why inside your `for` loop you do not just your condition for inclusion with an `if` and take appropriate action?

Comment: because multiple values there in my json data thats only i am place loop and storing the values inside another dictionary.. @CRD

Comment: You want to remove the values from the category response or from the 2nd array you have given?

Comment: from second array i have to remove ,which response have parent_id that data only have to display. @z22

Comment: @Kishorekumar - "multiple values", either to test or to copy, in no way precludes the use of an `if` (with or without an `else`). Your code would be along the lines of `if (condition is met, testing as many conditions with and/or as needed) { /* do whatever is needed when condition met using as many statements as you need */ } else { /* do anything that is needed when condition is not met, again using as many statements as you need */}`

Comment: @CRD i have edited my code,so find my frd what is wrong in it...........

Comment: @Kishorekumar - `@""` is an *empty string*, which is not the same as `nil` - one of your problems will probably be that your test needs to be a string equality check against the empty string (and BTW a dictionary cannot contain `nil`). **Note: You really should be showing the code you have written, the actual error messages and/or behaviour you get, and stating what you don't'the understand - people helping on SO don't usually debug code blobs without this.**

Comment: @Kishorekumar - Please accept the answer that helped you

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below. I have created a dummy dictionary and array as per your requirements.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setObject:@"" forKey:@"parent_id"];
[dict setObject:@"abc" forKey:@"name"];

NSMutableDictionary *dict1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict1 setObject:@"1" forKey:@"parent_id"];
[dict1 setObject:@"abcq" forKey:@"name"];

NSMutableDictionary *dict2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict2 setObject:@"" forKey:@"parent_id"];
[dict2 setObject:@"sss" forKey:@"name"];

NSMutableDictionary *dict3 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict3 setObject:@"2" forKey:@"parent_id"];
[dict3 setObject:@"ddd" forKey:@"name"];

arrTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arrTemp addObject:dict];[arrTemp addObject:dict1];[arrTemp addObject:dict2];[arrTemp addObject:dict3];

NSMutableIndexSet *indexesToDelete = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
NSUInteger currentIndex = 0;

for (id obj in arrTemp) {
    if([[obj objectForKey:@"parent_id"] isEqualToString:@""]){
        [indexesToDelete addIndex:currentIndex];
    }
    currentIndex++;
}

[arrTemp removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexesToDelete];
NSLog(@"%@", arrTemp);
```

Hope that helps. Let me know if it doesn't solve your issue.

Comment: Why `setValue` and not `setObject`?

Comment: @trojanfoe - yeah you are right, setObject would be more generic. Will correct it.

Comment: @z22 bro this work has been pending so wait with in two days i will accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

Your code fragment has a couple of issues:

1. You are testing the `"parent"` key against `Nil`.  The key will never be `nil` as they aren't allowed in Objective-C collection classes.  Instead test if `length > 0`.
2. You are removing objects from an array you are enumerating, effectively changing the array's length.  This will cause issues like *Index out-of-bounds* exceptions or missed elements.

The best thing is to create a new array and copy over elements that pass your test:

```
NSMutableArray filteredArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSDictionary *dict in arrDicName)
{
    NSString *parent = dict[@"parent"];
    if (parent.length > 0)
        [filteredArray addObject:dict];
}
arrDicName = filteredArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)isEmptyString:(NSString *)yourParentID
{
    BOOL isEmp = NO;

    if([[yourParentID stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length] == 0)
    {
        isEmp = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        isEmp = NO;
    }

    return isEmp;
}
```

follow the bellow code

```
NSString *parentId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrDicName objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"parent"]];

    if([self isEmptyString:parentId])
    {
        // Parent id is nil 
        // Do the rest
    }
    else
    {
        // Parent id is not nil
    }
```

Hope this will help you